# es6 arrow function, not getting param value in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi I have been trying to pass values to es6 arrow function in my React app, but not successful so far. Here is what I am doing

```
var data = [];
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  data.push(<li><a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.getData(e, i)} >{i}</a></li>);
}
```

and code for getData is

```
getData (e, page){
 e.preventDefault();
 //here I am calling an api to get data as per page params
}
```

but actually when the click happens i get nothing. Any help!

Comment: Remove the brackets - `onClick= (e)=>this.getTicketsPage(e,i)`

Comment: Arrow function and `this`? Arrow functions don't have `this` binding. `this` will be the context of first containing non-arrow function.

Comment: yep, try without brackets. http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Comment: but I am using this in React. not allowed without brackets

Comment: Add complete code. See [mcve].

Comment: @Weedoze and Jankapunkt - That's React syntax, and correct.

Comment: As @Tushar said, we need more context. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Can you add more code, as the first React syntax seems to be correct

Comment: kk you are right, did not see that he is in the html part. If so, this seems to be a binding issue.

Comment: Can you post the code for `getData`

Comment: @Aanchal ok, posting

Comment: and also the code where you are using these listitems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this code. It works ok - getData method is invoked when I click a link.

You just need to change `var` to `let` to get right value of `i` param.

```
var data = [];
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  data.push(<li><a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.getData(e, i)} >{i}</a></li>);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't change anything, let and var are basically the same. Also I think it's not good to have `var` and `let` mixed

Comment: @gisderdube var and let have different scopes.

Comment: true, but in this context i don't see where that would make a difference.

Comment: @Stanislav Mayorov yes it worked with e. but I am not getting the right value of i. now trying to debug, what can be the issue

Comment: @gisderdube every click using `var` will get 6 value.

Comment: @gisderdube The different is that cycle will be finished when handler will be invoked. 
https://jsbin.com/tohalemoma/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You're right. I didn't expect that. However, isn't this result caused by setting a Timeout? I think adding setTimeout will delay the function call by some ms (because it gets added to the callstack), whereas without it gets executed immediately. Therefore, var is 6 by the time the function gets executed (because it gets overwritten), whereas let has the expected value (because always a new instance).
In OPs example, he doesn't set a Timeout, so it shouldn't make a difference, right?

Comment: setTimeout will not be executed immediately. It will go to callback queue and will be executed after callstack will be empty.

Comment: @gisderdube No, he doesn't set a Timeout, but handler will work the same.

Comment: @StanislavMayorov This is probably off-topic now, but I'm really curious! Check this: http://jsbin.com/hipupadaxo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143671/discussion-between-stanislav-mayorov-and-gisderdube).

Comment: yeah, I am getting 6. Any solution?

Comment: @h_a86 Use let like I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Stanislav Mayorov thanks dear! You solved my problem. `let` worked for me. Really appreciated!

Comment: @h_a86 You are welcome. The solution using bind is ok too if you change arguments order in getData function.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var data = [];
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  data.push(<li><a href="#" onClick={this.getData.bind(this, i)}>{i}
    </a></li>);
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/lokafas/edit?html,js,console,output

By the way, I also recommend using `let` and `const` when you use ES6 syntax anyways.

Comment: Hmm... could you please provide the whole class? Are you using React.createClass() or ES6 classes? Try logging the args in getData and provide the result

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind `this` somewhere in order for your code to work. Best way is to do it in the constructor:

```
export default class SomeCoolName extends React.Component {

   constructor() {
      super();
      this.getData = this.getData.bind(this); // this is important!
   }

   getData(e, page) {
      // code
   }


   // somewhere in the code, in render() maybe
   var data = [];
   for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      data.push(<li><a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.getData(e, i)} >{i}</a></li>);
   }

}
```

Comment: is there a way to pass e here along with param `onClick={this.getData.bind(this, i)}` by this way I am getting correct value of i inside getData function

Comment: but unable to pass e